# Fantasy about the Moon coming down to Earth and getting caught in trees

Tags: story-identification

A rather haunting story I read when I was very young.

The Moon took the form of a beautiful woman who came down to the Earth and was ensnared by the trees.
The illustrated plates in it were quite well done.

For the life of me I haven't been able to find the book since.